# Checking for symmetry in a graph on the TI-84 Plus

Tags: calculator, symmetry

I was using the TI-84 Plus calculator to check for Y-Axis symmetry in the graph of "cos(2X+1)" and as I had to do it fast (I was in the middle of a test), I quickly noted that it was symmetrical. I had set the zoom to "ZTrig". 
This is (exactly)what I saw :

[image: cos(2X+1) graph on the TI-84]

But it turned out that the graph was not symmetrical. This is the graph by Google Graphs.

[image: cos(2X+1) graph on Google Graphs]

How do I identify correctly if a graph is symmetrical about an axis(Mostly the Y-axis) or not in the TI-84 Plus

**Update 1 :**

@Summea, This is what I got when I used the table method. This works fine, but is there a way to get the accuracy more than 5 digits as some problems may require it?

[image: Using the table method]

@Amzoti, I set the window variables like this (I changed the "Xscl" to 180, from 90, to see if it zooms in, but for some reason, the graph remains the same.

[image: Window options]

[image: New graph]

The small bars on the graph which indicate the points have really moved, but the graph remains the same.

I also tried another method, i.e. using the "ZBox" function to select a box and zoom in there. This is what I saw:

[image: Graph after zooming in "ZBox" function]

The graph hardly shows any difference, even now. How can I solve this?

Comment: It would seem that this might be an issue with trying to look at a global - like behavior on a very small screen and that it loses resolution and detail as a result. Is there a better way to zoom to see this on any limited size screen? I suppose you could have looked the the pieces of the graph in more detail, but this takes time. For example, look at [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+cos%282X%2B1%29) and see how it shows two levels of details. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could check for symmetry on the calculator is to check if the function being graphed is even or odd.

On the calculator:

1. Graph your equation by typing the equation into a `y=` slot.
2. Go to `TABLE SETUP` screen (by pressing `[2nd][TBLSET]`.)
3. Make sure that your *independent variable* (`x`) is set to `Ask`.
4. Then go to the `TABLE` screen (by pressing `[TABLE]` button.)
5. From there, you could try typing some values into the `x` column (for example, some "mirrored numbers" such as: `-4,-2,-1,1,2,4`) to see if there are any patterns going on with the `y` values for each `(negative)` and `(positive)` "pair" of numbers.

### Even Functions

If the `y` values for each corresponding `(negative)` and `(positive)` `x` are equal to each other, we can know that the graph is *even* and is *symmetrical* with respect to the y-axis.

Example: $y=x^2$

```
 x  | y
-4  | 16
-2  | 4
-1  | 1
 1  | 1
 2  | 4
 4  | 16
```

*(See how the `y` values "match up" with each other?)*

### Odd Functions

If the `y` values for each corresponding `(negative)` and `(positive)` `x` are the exact opposite of each other *(for example, `-1` and `1`)* we can know that the graph is *odd* and is *symmetrical* about the point of origin. (Sort of like a "diagonal symmetry".)

Example: $2x^3-4x$

```
 x  |  y
-4  | -112
-2  | -8
-1  |  2
 1  | -2
 2  |  8
 4  |  112
```

*(Notice how the `y` values "match up" with each other, but in this case, the `y` values are the exact opposite of each other with respect to the real number line.)*

Or in other words, if you took half of the graphed odd function's line (starting at the point of origin... which might be something like `(0,0)` on the graph,) and rotated the line 180 degrees about the point of origin, the line you moved would look the same as the line you didn't move.  *(Meaning, the lines would perfectly overlap.)*

*And note, this is just one simple way to check for symmetry; there are probably cases where a more-detailed process needs to be used.*

More information about Even and Odd functions on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions).

Comment: Thanks @Summea, that was exactly what I was looking for (The graph part)! Though, is there a way to get the values a little more accurately (In the graph)? I have updated my question to show this. I will be taking the SAT Math 2 soon and you just saved me a lot of time coding in TI Basic. Thanks!

Comment: @Hele Great to hear :)  Well, as far as getting more decimal values on your calculator, if you highlight the individual `y1` values in your `TABLE` (like in the first picture of your update above,) does it show you a more detailed version of that `y1` variable at the bottom of your calculator screen?

Comment: Yep! Problem solved. Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: @Hele Glad I could help a little! :)